# Find value in CSV column, return line number of the value

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a CSV file with contents:

```
scenario1,5,dosomething
scenario2,10,donothing
scenario3,8,dosomething
scenario4,5,donothing
```

I would like to take the contents of a variable to firstly see if it is in the first column, if true - I would like to get the row number where it is found and the entire line contents. There will be no duplicate values in column 1 of the csv.

I can partly do the first step which is to find if the variable is in the csv, returning the whole line.

```
import csv
filename = csv.reader(open('/file.csv', "rb"), delimiter=",")
v = 'scenario1'
for row in configfile:
    if 'v' in row[0]:
        print row
```

The results I receive would be:

```
['scenario1','5','dosomething']
```

But I need assistance with the second part please. This is to find the row number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv
with open("ooo.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line_num, content in enumerate(reader):
        if content[0] == "scenario1":
            print content, line_num + 1
```

Or without csv module:

```
with open("ooo.csv") as f:
    for l, i in enumerate(f):
        data = i.split(",")
        if data[0] == "scenario1":
            print data, l + 1
```

Output:

```
['scenario1', '5', 'dosomething'] 1
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you, I used the first scenario with the csv module.